# Boostrap modal hidden behind backdrop in Firefox only

Tags: html, css, firefox, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on getting a link public, but was hoping someone would see the title and already familiar with the problem.

In Firefox only:

The modal backdrop is covering the modal popup. I've checked z-index properties over and over again. It works in IE7+ and all other browsers.

I will update this post with a link as soon as possible.

Thank you, and I apologize for the lack of an example.